# Python: How to store user text input in a file?

Tags: python, file, text, input, store

I'm trying to prompt the user to enter a block of text until he/she types EOF on a separate line by itself. After that, the program should present him/her with a menu. When I go to Option 1, it only prints out EOF and not everything that was typed earlier. Why is this?

Let's say I type "Hi I like pie" as my block of text. I type EOF to head to the menu and type option 1. I expect "Hi I like pie" to pop up but only the letters EOF does. How do I fix this? How do I "feed" a Python file?

```
#Prompt the user to enter a block of text.
done = False
while(done == False):
    textInput = input()
    if textInput == "EOF":
        break

#Prompt the user to select an option from the Text Analyzer Menu.
print("Welcome to the Text Analyzer Menu! Select an option by typing a number"
    "\n1. shortest word"
    "\n2. longest word"
    "\n3. most common word"
    "\n4. left-column secret message!"
    "\n5. fifth-words secret message!"
    "\n6. word count"
    "\n7. quit")

option = 0

while option !=7:
    option = int(input())

    if option == 1:
        print(textInput)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in your `while` loop, you loop until `textInput` is equal to `EOF`, so you only print `EOF`

You can try something like this (by using a `nextInput` variable to "preview" the next input):

```
#Prompt the user to enter a block of text.
done = False
nextInput = ""
while(done == False):
    nextInput= input()
    if nextInput== "EOF":
        break
    else:
        textInput += nextInput
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response sir.

Comment: No problem!  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you set

```
textInput = input()
```

you throw away the old input. If you want to keep all the input, you should make a list:

```
input_list = []
text_input = None
while text_input != "EOF":
    text_input = input()
    input_list.append(text_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time the user types a new line in, your textInput variable gets overwritten.

You could do

```
textInput = ''
done = False
while(done == False):
    input = input()
    if input == "EOF":
        break
    textInput += input
```

Also, you don't need to use both a `done` variable and the break statement.
you could either do

```
done = False
while(done == False):
    textInput += input()
    if textInput == "EOF":
        done = True
```

or

```
while True:
    textInput += input()
    if textInput == "EOF":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save every line typed in your while loop as it is typed. Each time the user types a new line, the variable textInput is overwritten. You can use store text to a text file like this:

```
writer = open("textfile.txt" , "w")
writer.write(textInput + "\n")
```

Insert this as an elif statement after your if in the while loop. The "\n" is a new line command which does not show up when the text is read, but tells the computer to start a new line.

In order to read this file, use this code:

```
reader = open("textfile.txt" , "r")
print(reader.readline()) #line 1
print(reader.readline()) #line 2
```

There are various other methods for reading the file the different ways you want to for you program, which you can research on your own.